# Lucene index creation is not working

Tags: search, sitecore, lucene

I am trying to create an index based through Lucene in Sitecore 6.5 through App.Config on one of the content item template. Remember the **'master'** listed here is the **SC DB** not the physical SQL DB. 
Here is my code:

```
    <configuration xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <databases>
      <database id="master" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
          <obj type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)HistoryStorage, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <param connectionStringName="$(id)" />
            <EntryLifeTime>30.00:00:00</EntryLifeTime>
          </obj>
        </Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
        <Engines.HistoryEngine.SaveDotNetCallStack>false</Engines.HistoryEngine.SaveDotNetCallStack>
      </database>
    </databases>
    <search>
      <configuration>
        <indexes>
          <index id="master" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">master</param>
            <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <master type="Sitecore.SharedSource.Search.Crawlers.AdvancedDatabaseCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.Search">
                <Database>master</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/Data</Root>
                <IndexAllFields>false</IndexAllFields>
                <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
                  <template1>{EF11A8D0-D373-4A4B-90BA-16984D277612}</template1>
                </include>
                <fieldCrawlers hint="raw:AddFieldCrawlers">
                  <fieldCrawler type="Sitecore.SharedSource.Search.FieldCrawlers.LookupFieldCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.Search" fieldType="Single-Line Text" />
                  <fieldCrawler type="Sitecore.SharedSource.Search.FieldCrawlers.DateFieldCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.Search" fieldType="Multilist" />
                </fieldCrawlers>
                <!-- If a field type is not defined, defaults of storageType="NO", indexType="UN_TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" are applied-->
                <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldTypes">
                  <!-- Text fields need to be tokenized -->
                  <fieldType name="single-line text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="multi-line text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="word document" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="html" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="rich text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="memo" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <!-- Multilist based fields need to be tokenized to support search of multiple values -->
                  <fieldType name="multilist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="treelist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="treelistex" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="checklist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <!-- Legacy tree list field from ver. 5.3 -->
                  <fieldType name="tree list" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                </fieldTypes>
              </master>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </search>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

When I am running my solution after this I am looking my indexes through 'Index Viewer' but couldn't see anything. What I am doing wrong here?

I added this code:

```
  private IDictionary<string, Sitecore.Search.Index> GetSearchIndexes()
    {
        var _configuration = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("search/configuration", true) as Sitecore.Search.SearchConfiguration;
        return _configuration.Indexes;
    }
```

But in the return of _configuration.Indexes I am getting: master, web, advanced. My index is different, these are the list of DBs.

Comment: when you say that you can't see anything in the index viewer do you mean that you can't see any documents or does the index not appear in the list?

Comment: Index does not appear in the list.

Comment: I read in your comment below that you chose DataIndex as the type but what you are creating above is a SearchIndex. Do you see it if you select SearchIndex as the type?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `web.config` and not `app.config`.

Go to **Sitecore > Control Panel > Database > Rebuild the Search Index** to generate the index on the file system.

Or, download [this script](http://resources.alexshyba.com/blog/RebuildDatabaseCrawlers.zip) and run it.

Comment: Hey Mark: I add this file under myProjectName->App_Config->Include->myName.Config

Comment: After doing what you said, I went to IndexViewer and Selectted Index Type = DataIndex, Database = Master. But in the Index dropdown I see nothing :(

Comment: Run the script instead, I added a link to it.

Comment: I added the code in my question. I am getting the DBs names as the return value of the function above (I took the code from the Alex's code).